# Adding extra parameter in QGIS processing in grass to close files after processing

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, qgis-processing, grass-7.4

The code below works but as this involves averaging thousands of files, grass shows an error message:

```
Too many open files
```

The code:

```
ymax=31.4648437503
ymin=17.4068080185
xmax=-80.4330407378
xmin=-98.0539218184
raster_list = create_qgis_raster(files)
general.runalg('grass7:r.series', raster_list, False, 0,
   '-10000000000,10000000000',
   '%f,%f,%f,%f' % (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax),
   0, output_path
)
```

The error happens because grass don't close these raster layers. [The documentation](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass77/manuals/r.series.html) of grass `r.series` algorithm has a flag called `-z` that means `Do not keep files open`. However, there is no place to put this option in `runlang` method of `processing`.

When I add the parameter `-z`, I get the error

```
Error: Wrong number of parameters
ALGORITHM: r.series - Makes each output cell value a function of the 
values assigned to the corresponding cells in the input raster layers.
   input <ParameterMultipleInput>
   -n <ParameterBoolean>
   method <ParameterSelection>
   range <ParameterString>
   GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER <ParameterExtent>
   GRASS_REGION_CELLSIZE_PARAMETER <ParameterNumber>
   output <OutputRaster>
```

QGIS version 2.18

Is there any way of adding those additional flags of `r.series` in processing `runlang` method?

Edit:
Joseph's answer helped in adding the extra parameter but the added parameter has not closed open files after processing.

Comment: Which version of QGIS?

Comment: @ndawson Sorry not to mention that. It is 2.18. I will update the question.

Answer (score 3):

Inside your QGIS directory, find the `r.series.txt` file. For example in Windows:

```
C:/Program Files/QGIS 2.18/apps/qgis-ltr/python/plugins/processing/algs/grass7/description/r.series.txt
```

And in Linux:

```
/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/algs/grass7/description/r.series.txt
```

It will look something like this:

```
r.series
Makes each output cell value a function of the values assigned to the corresponding cells in the input raster layers.
Raster (r.*)
ParameterMultipleInput|input|Input raster layer(s)|3.0|False
ParameterBoolean|-n|Propagate NULLs|False
ParameterSelection|method|Aggregate operation|average;count;median;mode;minimum;min_raster;maximum;max_raster;stddev;range;sum;variance;diversity;slope;offset;detcoeff;quart1;quart3;perc90;skewness;kurtosis
*ParameterString|range|Ignore values outside this range (lo,hi)|-10000000000,10000000000
OutputRaster|output|Aggregated
```

The following line shows how the `-n` flag is set:

```
ParameterBoolean|-n|Propagate NULLs|False
```

Let's copy this but set it for the `-z` flag instead and insert it immediately after. If you're feeling whimsy, make it checked as default:

```
ParameterBoolean|-n|Propagate NULLs|False
ParameterBoolean|-z|Do not keep files open|True
```

Now save the file. If you cannot due to permission reasons, save the file in another location (i.e. desktop). Delete the original file then move the newly saved one from the desktop in its place. **Restart QGIS** and when you run the same tool, you should see the new parameter:

[image: r.series tool]

The python code should change to the following. True is added for the added as a third parameter for `Don't keep files open` paramerter:

```
general.runalg('grass7:r.series', raster_list, False, True, 0, 
   '-10000000000,10000000000',
   '%f,%f,%f,%f' % (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax),
   0, output_path
)
```

---

*Unfortunately I do not have many rasters to test this on so good luck!*

Comment: Unfortunately, following your instruction helped in addition the parameter. However, I am still `Getting too many files`.

Comment: It looks like this question is answered but shall I ask another question for grass issue?

Comment: @wondim - Perhaps edit your question to mention that you tried the solution I posted but the problem persists. Then hopefully another could offer a working solution or advice :)

Comment: I have edited the question.